# What urpmi source can I use with Mandriva Entreprise Server 5.2?

Tags: linux, repository, server

I have to install several packages for a customer on an old server using Mandriva Entreprise Server 5.2 (MES5).

I have asked my customer for the DVD-ROM but he didn't find it, so I would like to know if there is an online compatible repository.

I have found several repositories such as : ftp://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/mandriva-prehistory/ , ftp://distrib-coffee.ipsl.jussieu.fr/pub/linux/MandrivaLinux/official/ or http://plf.zarb.org/mirrors/

Unfortunately there is no "mes5" or "5.2" respository. Could anyone please tell me if/what repository could I use ?

NB : I can install tarballs but it would be easier for me not to have to. Dist changing/upgrading is not a solution because it's just an old server that is likely to be replaced in a couple of years.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a Mandriva repository at ftp.free.fr, I could install all the missing packages !

Here is my /etc/urpmi/urpmi.cfg :

```
{
}

Mandriva\ Linux\ -\ MES5\ -\ x86_64\ DVD cdrom://x86_64/media/main {
  key-ids: db032a8a
}

Mandriva\ Linux\ -\ MES5\ -\ x86_64\ DVD\ (non-free) cdrom://x86_64/media/non-free {
  key-ids: db032a8a
}

Main ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/main/release {
  key-ids: 70771ff3
}

Main\ Updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/main/updates {
  key-ids: 22458a98
  update
}

Main32 ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/i586/media/main/release {
  key-ids: 70771ff3
}

Main32\ Updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/i586/media/main/updates {
  key-ids: 22458a98
  update
}

Main\ Testing ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/main/testing {
  ignore
}

Main\ Backports ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/main/backports {
  ignore
}

Main\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_main/release {
  ignore
}

Main\ Updates\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_main/updates {
  ignore
}

Main\ Testing\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_main/testing {
  ignore
}

Main\ Backports\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_main/backports {
  ignore
}

Contrib ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/contrib/release {
  key-ids: 78d019f5
}

Contrib\ Updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/contrib/updates {
  key-ids: 26752624
  update
}

Contrib\ Testing ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/contrib/testing {
  ignore
}

Contrib\ Backports ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/contrib/backports {
  ignore
}

Contrib\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_contrib/release {
  ignore
}

Contrib\ Updates\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_contrib/updates {
  ignore
}

Contrib\ Testing\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_contrib/testing {
  ignore
}

Contrib\ Backports\ debug ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_contrib/backports {
  ignore
}

Non-free ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/non-free/release {
  key-ids: 70771ff3
}

Non-free\ Updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/non-free/updates {
  key-ids: 26752624
  update
}

Non-free\ Testing ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/non-free/testing {
  ignore
}

Non-free\ Backports ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/non-free/backports {
  ignore
}

debug_non-free_release ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_non-free/release {
  ignore
}

debug_non-free_updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_non-free/updates {
  ignore
}

debug_non-free_testing ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_non-free/testing {
  ignore
}

debug_non-free_backports ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/debug_non-free/backports {
  ignore
}

Restricted ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/restricted/release {
  ignore
}

Restricted\ Updates ftp://ftp.free.fr/pub/Distributions_Linux/MandrivaLinux/official/current/x86_64/media/restricted/updates {
  ignore
  update
}
```